# Clang claims that `member reference base type 'X' is not a structure or union`, but X is a structure template with deduced parameters

Tags: c++, clang, c++17, template-argument-deduction, compiler-bug

Consider following code:

```
template <typename T> struct X
{
    X(T) {}
    void foo() {}
};

template <typename T> struct Y
{
    int object = 0;

    void bar()
    {
        X(object).foo();
    }
};
```

<kbd>**[Live on gcc.godbold.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'template+%3Ctypename+T%3E+struct+X%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++++X(T)+%7B%7D%0D%0A++++void+foo()+%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E+struct+Y%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++++int+object+%3D+0%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A++++void+bar()%0D%0A++++%7B%0D%0A++++++++X(object).foo()%3B%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:45.503705913267396,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:37.133540842555846,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+gcc+8.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:28.685411942357064,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang700,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+7.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:51.20483360016142,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+7.0.0',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:25.81088214437556,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)**</kbd>

GCC 8.2 compiles it, while Clang 7 spits out following error:

> ```
> <source>:13:18: error: member reference base type 'X' is not a structure or union
>         X(object).foo();
>         ~~~~~~~~~^~~~
> ```

This looks like a bug to me.

The conditions are very specific: If either structure is not a template, or if `object` is not a member variable, or if CTAD (class template argument deduction) is not involved, then Clang compiles the code as well.

What's going on here? Is it indeed a Clang bug?

And what's more important, how can I make the code compile with minimal changes, preferrably without getting rid of CTAD?

---

The only flag used is `-std=c++17`.

`clang++ --version` is

> ```
> clang version 7.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_700/final 342594)
> Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
> Thread model: posix
> ```

Comment: Or maybe not, but this error occurs when you're referencing a type that the compiler cannot deduce. maybe `X<int>(object)` would fix it.

Comment: Also `auto a = X(object); a.foo();` fixes it.

Comment: @sturcotte06 If that works his code should work as well.

Comment: @sturcotte06 Adding `<int>` fixes it (as the question mentions), but I want to use CTAD, since my actual code is more complicated. Making a temporary variable seems like a good workaround, and this is what I'm doing while waiting for a better solution or a Clang bugfix.

Comment: I think the best workaround until clang gets fixed is to go old-school and use a function for the template deduction: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/M3HxCN

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is clang bug see  [Class template argument deduction with deduced type fails when accessing member](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39663) which says:

> Try to compile the following c++ program:
>
> ```
>   template <class T>
>   struct C {
>     C(T) {}
>     int a;
>   };
>
>   template <class T>
>   int foo(T v) {
>     return C{v}.a; // <----
>   }
>
>   int main() {
>     foo(4);
>   }
> ```
>
> The line marked above fails with the error:
>
> ```
> error: member reference base type 'C' is not a structure or union
>     return (C{v}).a;
>            ~~~~~~^~
> ```

The bug report also specifies cases that do work, which may or may not be alternatives.

> Note that the following all work fine:
>
> ```
>   template <class T>
>   C<T> foo(T v) {
>     return C{v};
>   }
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> int foo(int v) {
>     return C{v}.a;
>   }
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
>   C{4}.a;
> ```
>
> I tried this also on a recent trunk build (trunk 346600)